# AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name

Tags: server, apache2

When I write this `apache2 -S`, I am getting this message:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Comment: That's a warning. That won't stop Apache from starting.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error, it is just a warning and you can safely ignore it. What it is saying is that `ServerName` is not set, so it will assume machine IP as the same.

If you look at the default config `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`, you will see that the `ServerName` directive is commented like this:

```
#ServerName www.example.com
```

If you want to remove the AH00558 error, you have to configure your `ServerName`.